# Interface with synchronous methods vs. asynchronous implementation: clean way to solve?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Assume you have a settings interface with only sync methods or properties.

You must implement this simple interface because that's what some library wants you to do.

```
public interface ISettings
{
  // This could also be a GetLoginName() and SetLoginName().
  string LoginName { get; set; }
}
```

Your code already has some functionality to save user configuration, but it is completely async (maybe using some async DB connection or writing the config async into some cloud based web service - whatever). You'd like to reuse your code to implement `ISettings`.

By now, we all know that blocking async code is almost always a guarantee to [deadlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (just picking one of the many articles dealing with the issue).

So what to do? The naive approach below might deadlock, so not a real option:

```
public class ConcreteSettings : ISettings
{
  SqlConnectionAsync asyncConn;

  // Async in properties is always bad, I know; 
  // props are meant to be fast-non-blocking as Damien correctly states.
  // But the interface could also have a SetLoginName() and GetLoginName()
  // method - same problem in the end.
  public string LoginName
  {
    get
    {
      var t = this.asyncConn.Table<Config>().GetValueAsync("loginName");
      // Bad idea because if GetValueAsync() wants to execute a continuation
      // after its async code parts, it will deadlock.
      return t.Result;
    }
    set
    {
      var t = this.asyncConn.InsertOrUpdateAsync("loginName", value);
      // Same argument as above: this can deadlock.
      t.Wait();
    }
  }
}
```

As an alternative I was thinking about forcing execution into the thread pool:

```
...
get
{
  var t = Task.Run(async () => {
    return await this.asyncConn.Table<Config>().GetValueAsync("loginName");
  }).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return t.Result;
}
...
```

This can IMHO not deadlock - still it feels very tacky.

My last idea is to implement the interface using some in-memory properties and then add an async `PersistToDatabaseAsync()` method to my concrete implementation which I call at some point in my code. Problem is that it's my code that is responsible for saving and for more complex interface it might not be possible to keep everything in memory.

What is the cleanest solution for this problem? Is there one at all?

Comment: Contact the library author and ask when they're going to support async? (Also, by the by, properties aren't generally async, and don't support `async`/`await` since they're meant to be fast and non-blocking)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, that's what I'd probably do. :-) However this is more of a hypothetical question/case.

Comment: Stephen Toub devoted a blog post to [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for async methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx), which, at the bottom, covers implementations for if you "have to", as here, actually do so. They're similar to your suggestions in your question.

Comment: Horizon problem, solve it by adding a private string member and return its value.  How it is going to get a value is entirely up to you, the implementation is in your control.

Comment: @Krumelur I've provided you a possible anwer. As Damien_The_Unbeilever has said as comment in my answer, my answer would be fine if you could modify the library code. Is this what you call "hypothetical question/case"? If not, I'll drop the answer...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The link to Stephen's post is great information.